# How to pass extra variables in URL with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, get

I am having trouble trying to pass an extra variable in the url to my WordPress installation.

For example `/news?c=123`

For some reason, it works only on the website root `www.example.com?c=123` but it does not work if the url contains any more information `www.example.com/news?c=123`. I have the following code in my functions.php file in the theme directory.

```
if (isset($_GET['c'])) 
{
  setcookie("cCookie", $_GET['c']); 
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
  setcookie("rCookie", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: [This question on wordpress.stackexchange explains the process](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48487/how-to-retrieve-get-variables-from-rewritten-urls)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are quite few solutions to tackle this issue. First you can go for a plugin if you want:

- [WordPress Quickie: Custom Query String Plugin](http://paulstamatiou.com/wordpress-quickie-custom-query-string-plugin)

Or code manually, check out this post:

- [Passing Query String Parameters in WordPress URL](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/)

Also check out:

- [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)

Comment: I have a feeling that first plugin has been discontinued.

Answer (score 127):

To make the round trip "The WordPress Way" on the "front-end" (doesn't work in the context of `wp-admin`), you need to use 3 WordPress functions:

- [add_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) - to create the URL with your new query variable ('c' in your example)
- the [query_vars](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) filter - to modify the list of [public query variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) that WordPress knows about (this only works on the front-end, because the WP Query is not used on the back end - `wp-admin` - so this will also not be available in `admin-ajax`)
- [get_query_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) - to retrieve the value of your custom query variable passed in your URL.

Note: there's no need to even touch the superglobals (`$_GET`) if you do it this way.

## Example

**On the page where you need to create the link / set the query variable:**

*if it's a link back to this page, just adding the query variable*

```html
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'c', $my_value_for_c ) )?>">
```

*if it's a link to some other page*

```html
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( 
    add_query_arg( 'c', $my_value_for_c, site_url( '/some_other_page/' ) ) 
    )?>">
```

**In your functions.php, or some plugin file or custom class (front-end only):**

```php
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "c";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

**On the page / function where you wish to retrieve and work with the query var set in your URL:**

```php
$my_c = get_query_var( 'c' );
```

### On the Back End (`wp-admin`)

On the back end we don't ever run `wp()`, so the main WP Query does not get run. As a result, there are no `query vars` and the `query_vars` hook is not run.

In this case, you'll need to revert to the more standard approach of examining your `$_GET` superglobal. The best way to do this is probably:

```php
$my_c = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "c", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

though in a pinch you could do the tried and true

```php
$my_c = isset( $_GET['c'] ) ? $_GET['c'] : "";
```

or some variant thereof.

Comment: Also you need to use `esc_url` with `add_query_arg` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Comment: This is a great answer, been looking ages for a simple example like this, thanks

Comment: Great description! Does wordpress strip out unregistered query arguments (it seems to be for me, but I'm not totally sure what's going on)? it would be good to state this if so, to alleviate confusion :)

Comment: It doesn't take them out of $_GET, but they're not available to your rewrite rules or within your `$query_vars`

Comment: @electroid if you're not sure what your variable may contain, then absolutely, especially if it's coming from user input (ie: $_REQUEST)

Comment: @electroid modified my answer to reflect your best practice.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! How would I alter the function to work with multiple values?

Answer (score 18):

Since this is a frequently visited post i thought to post my solution in case it helps anyone. **In WordPress along with using query vars you can change permalinks too like this**

```
www.example.com?c=123 to www.example.com/c/123
```

For this you have to add these lines of code in functions.php or your plugin base file.

From **[shankhan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586888/7198013) anwer**

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addnew_query_vars', 10, 1 );
function addnew_query_vars($vars)
{   
    $vars[] = 'c'; // c is the name of variable you want to add       
    return $vars;
}
```

And additionally this snipped to add custom rewriting rules.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^c/([0-9]+)/?', '?c=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

**For the case where you need to add rewrite rules for a specifc page you can use that page slug to write a rewrite rule for that specific page. Like in the question OP has asked about**

```
www.example.com/news?c=123 to www.example.com/news/123
```

We can change it to the desired behaviour by adding a little modification to our previous function.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/([0-9]+)/?', 'news?c=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Hoping that it becomes useful for someone.

Comment: Thanks. Much helpfull

Comment: Thanks, it really helps.

Comment: Is it possible to add the rewrite rule in a way that it's universal, no matter what page, archive or similar is before, say /c/123?

Comment: Yes, that is what this code does. The function before "For the Case" line

Comment: How can we use this to pass multiple parameters? Like news=123 & category=stories

Comment: i always get 404 page when trying to add this code. I have a link of a page and i need to paginate a result. My custom page file has to paginate results. So i have to have a link like page/pagination/2 and get the number 2 to paginate the sql. Anybody knows how to pass this variable?

Comment: You wanted to be hellpfull? You helped a lot!

Answer (score 15):

add following code in function.php

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addnew_query_vars', 10, 1 );
function addnew_query_vars($vars)
{   
    $vars[] = 'var1'; // var1 is the name of variable you want to add       
    return $vars;
}
```

then you will b able to use $_GET['var1']

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$edit_post = add_query_arg('c', '123', 'news' );

?>

<a href="<?php echo $edit_post; ?>">Go to New page</a>
```

You can add any page inplace of "news".

Answer (score 4):

One issue you might run into is `is_home()` returns true when a registered query_var is present in the home URL. For example, if `http://example.com` displays a static page instead of the blog, `http://example.com/?c=123` will return the blog.

See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143 and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-query-var-makes-front-page-missing/ for more info on this.

What you can do (if you're not attempting to affect the query) is use `add_rewrite_endpoint()`. It should be run during the `init` action as it affects the rewrite rules. Eg.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_setcookie_rewrite_endpoints' );

function add_custom_setcookie_rewrite_endpoints() {
    //add ?c=123 endpoint with
    //EP_ALL so endpoint is present across all places
    //no effect on the query vars
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'c', EP_ALL, $query_vars = false );
}
```

This should give you access to `$_GET['c']` when the url contains more information like `www.example.com/news?c=123`.

Remember to flush your rewrite rules after adding/modifying this.

Answer (score 3):

to **add parameter to post urls** (to perma-links), i use this:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
function append_query_string( $url, $post ) 
{
    return add_query_arg('my_pid',$post->ID, $url);
}
```

output:

`http://yoursite.com/pagename?my_pid=12345678`

Comment: @mwebber the answer was not aimed to give answer "how to detect ? or # in url", but to show a hook to modify the url. However, as you wished, I've updated the answer to comply with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This was the only way I could get this to work

```
add_action('init','add_query_args');
function add_query_args()
{ 
    add_query_arg( 'var1', 'val1' );
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

Answer (score -1):

In your case, Just add / after url and then put query arguments. like

`www.example.com/news/?c=123` or `news/?c=123`

instead of

`www.example.com/news?c=123` or `news?c=123`

Comment: it didn't work for me