# How to pass one or more variables to a permalink on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a page which I need to send two variables, `'my_book_id'` and `'library_book_id'`.

On that page I would code something that uses the variables.

I know that since WordPress pages are not exactly HTML pages or PHP files, I can't send variables via the URL and then get them for use on the page with `$_GET['my_book_id']`.

I want to implement something like [this](http://www.mysite.com/show_page?my_book_id=1&library_book_id=12). How would I do it?

I am using permalinks and I have `%postname%` on the definitions.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use:

```
<?php echo get_permalink( $page_id ) . '?my_book_id=' . 1 . '&library_book_id=' . 12; ?>
```

On the place where the link is build

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but i found this plugin : http://phpbase.in/free-scripts/qstring-wordpress-plugin/ and this exactly what i want ....thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just use

```
    $_GET['my_book_id']
```

You can either get the variable by coding in your page/post template or,

(much better) by creating a plugin