# A variable in the url is not being read using isset

Tags: php, wordpress

My address is www.mysite.com/test-url?tx=test

```
if (isset($_GET['tx'])) {
    echo 'Success';

 }
```

However nothings happening at all, its simply not reading the fact that the variable is there

Comment: Your code checked out for me. You might have something in your `.htaccess` that's playing tricks on you or elsewhere.

Comment: Try `if (isset($_GET['tx']) && $_GET['tx'] == test) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw in a comment you wrote, you mentioned that you're on WordPress.

TBH, I'm not a Wordpress guy therefore I wouldn't be able to help and troubleshoot it in a greater scope, but do try the following by adding an extra conditional statement to match the word `test` in the GET.

The following was successful on my server (not Wordpress). If the URL was `test-url?tx=` it would fail and if it were `test-url?tx=testx` it would also fail, therefore only `test-url?tx=test` will be deemed as successful.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['tx']) && $_GET['tx'] == test) {
    echo 'Success.';

 }

else {
echo "Sorry, the parameter is not set or is invalid.";
}
```

---

**Edit**

[`Have a look`](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/) at this and [`this Q&A`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4586835/) where I found the first one from.

I Google'd `"if (isset($_GET not working with wordpress php"` here you will find many other results, am sure.

Comment: Thanks but it must definitely something to do with wordpress because this didnt work either for some reason

Comment: You're welcome Adrian. I wish I could help you further, but as I stated (in my answer) I'm not a Wordpress guy, and thought that by adding the additional conditional statement, that it would have helped. @Adrian

Comment: You're welcome @Adrian - If I think of anything (or find) I'll let you know.

Comment: [`Have a look at this`](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/) and [`this Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4586835/) where I found the first one from. I Google'd `"if (isset($_GET not working with wordpress php"` @Adrian where you will find many other results, am sure.

Comment: feel free to edit your answer with the link and Ill give it a tick :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your `.htaccess` file,

so, where you'll have something like this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You'll need to add `QSA` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
                                             ^^^^
```

This tells the server to append the query string.. [**more info at apache.org**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Thanks its wordpress, I tried this and it still didnt work unfortunately

Comment: what happens if you replace `?` with `&` in your URL?

Comment: can you post the contents of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: hi I found a way around it by using `get_query_var` and adding the get variable in my functions.php

Comment: That's great news Adrian. Did you happen to find it from one of the links I gave you? I noticed it's in there. @Adrian