# Pass query string variable to WordPress page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a fully-functional WordPress site with a URL structure like this:

```
http://example.com/friendlyurl/
```

But I would like to be able to pass an ID number like this (or whatever URL structure would work):

```
http://example.com/friendlyurl/?id=123
```

I have a custom page template that will handle everything from there, I just need a simple way to get the number to the page template. I.e.:

```
$id=trim($_GET["id"]);
```

I am not a WordPress whiz, just looking for a simple solution here to solve a problem. Would appreciate any advice or direction.

Thank you!

Comment: What you are suggesting should work fine - what problems are you getting

Comment: When I try to pull in the variable's contents, I don't get anything. I do an "echo" and its just blank. Its always possible I have a problem with that part of the code, I was not assuming my URL would work with WordPress.

Comment: Hmm, seems you are correct, not used wp for a while. Take a look here for possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

Comment: @RobertLee Unless I'm misunderstanding, that function just lets you modify a URL, it doesn't do anything to accept an incoming query variable value?

Comment: Oddly enough, it was not working before, but seems to now. I'm not sure what I changed. So my original URL is fine to use like that?

Comment: If all your trying to do is pass the number in an ID then you would want to use add_query_arg to add that id value and pass it to the link you are trying to send that value to.