# PHP — Undefined Variable with $_GET Test

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, variables, get

I have a form in the sidebar on the following WP site — http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~devchewengco/

Here is part of the code I'm using for the results page:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['ApplianceType']) || isset($_GET['brand'])) : // search filter form ?>
    <?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=ASC') ?>
        <?php get_template_part('loop', 'feed-products' ); ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php else : // display categories as default ?>
    <?php get_template_part('include', 'feed-categories-products' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But the statement is always returning false. Originally, I had it *without* the `isset()` function, but that was giving me undefined variable errors

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why your every line contains `<?php` and `?>` if there is only PHP in code and no other language?

Comment: if(condition){ code; }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress

Comment: try echo '<pre>';print_r($_GET); echo '</pre>'; and let us know the result

Comment: @Justinas Have you ever seen what WP files look like? (no idea why they chose that approach though)

Comment: @Shomz yes, and what's the difference between WordPress `.php` file and Yii `.php` file (except operations)? If you see wrong code you continue to write code or you try to fix your own code to be good?

Comment: @Riad thanks, I've given that a shot. It tells me it's an empty array

Comment: @Justinas I'd always try to follow the existing style (that's WP, a highly established framework, not a plugin from some lame dev in which case I'd consider rewriting), no matter what I think about it. So you'd rewrite all the WP theme files and then when there's an update - BOOM. Here we go again.

Comment: @Shomz No, you don't rewrite everything. Only what you have updated. I personally follow PSR-2. Your `BOOM` will be only if you rewrite core of framework. In other case it's safe to change files since they will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just found that in this [URL](http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~devchewengco/products/?ApplianceType=washing-machines&Brand=heubsch) you have the undefined warning. You have to use:

```
isset($_GET['Brand'])  // you are using 'brand'
```

Comment: thanks, I've fixed that but it's still not working unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

You are not necessarily doing something wrong. If you are getting "undefined variable" errors without the `isset`-checks, it probably means the `ApplianceType` and `brand` key in the `$_GET` array are undefined.

They are either removed or simply not set.