# Passing params in WordPress URL

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a WordPress site with integration of certain PHP scripts. PHP script requires `day=some_number` as param in the URL.

For eg: `xyz.com/book-session-time/?month=12&day=09`

Unfortunately this is causing 404 issue. I think WordPress is getting confused with the day param. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: day is reserved term ... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Comment: You need to give some code relating to this.Thn nd thn someone will help you ..

Comment: You can force it to work like this : `if(is_404() && isset($_GET['day'])){locate_template('YOURCUSTOMETEMPLATE.PHP', true);}` wrap this code into the function and use `template_redirect` action.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress