# How to keep menu through pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

The main page contain manu1 and articles
The subpage contain menu2 and articles
Articles uses "single.php" template

How to achive this:
When I click on the article at main page; menu1 should be used (as on the main page)
When I click on the article at subpage; menu2 should be used (as on the subpage)

[image: Here is visualization]

*My question refer to menu but it could be any piece of code or widget

Comment: You need to provide details of what you have tried and specifics of your environment (e.g. are you using a pre-built theme, are you using a custom built/starter/child theme, if you're coding the templates, where's your code samples)

Comment: @Ryan I just add visualization. I am building this template from scratch. I don't have code for single.php yet. Code for index and page-subpage are very generic and looks like <header><menu><the loop><footer>

Answer (score 0):

I found hint here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362383/1379570

I will set **URL variable** at "index" and diffrent variable value at "page-subpage" so I will be able to distinguish that I should use menu1 or menu2 on the single.php page.