# Removing duplicate data from Array loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am trying to remove duplicate iterations from my post loop, and it seems that my code is working perfectly the only issue is that my `&posts_per_page=21` declare is no longer present, it displays only 3 results for example (*which are the unique titles*)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'     => 'post',
  'order'         => 'ASC',
  'orderby'       => 'title'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$unique_artist = array();
query_posts($query_string.'&cat=7&posts_per_page=21'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

// title example for post "Artist - Song Name"
$title = get_the_title();
$artist = explode('-', $title);
$main_artist = $artist[0];

$aArtist = $main_artist;
if( ! in_array( $aArtist, $unique_artist ) ) :
    $unique_artist[] = $aArtist;

    the_title(); 

endif;  endwhile; endif;
```

How can I make it so that no matter what, my `post_per_page` will display the 21 desired results?  Instead of only showing the unique titles, when we remove the duplicates..

Comment: Check out this question to see if it solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress

Comment: You'd have to keep querying the database until you have 21 items exactly.

Comment: You sure that you have at least 21 posts for Category ID 7 in your DB?